# Missed Garbage Collection Notifications

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

We are running a web farm using .NET. Each web server holds a considerable amount of static objects in it's memory. A Gen 2 garbage collection (GC) takes 10-20 seconds and it runs every 5 minutes.
We ran more or less into the same problems that StackOverflow ran into: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector

At the moment, we are reducing the number of objects in the cache. However, this takes time.

At the same time, we implemented the methods documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx) to get notifications in .NET about approaching GCs.
The goal is to take a web server out of the farm when a GC is approaching and include it into the farm after the GC is over.
However, we only get a notification for 0.7% of all GCs.
We are using a maxGenerationThreshold and largeObjectHeapThreshold of 8. We tried other thresholds, but the amount of missed GCs did not change.

We are using concurrent server garbage collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx). The GCLatencyMode is Interactive (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode.aspx). Here again, we tried to use other GC modes (Workstation mode, Batch, etc.). And again we did not get a notification for most of the GCs.

Are we doing something wrong, or is it impossible to get a notification for every GC that occurs?
How can we increase the number of notifications?

According to http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/assets/Under_the_Hood_of_.NET_Management.pdf, at the beginning a GC is triggered when Gen2 hits ~10 MB. We have a lot of RAM, so if we could set this threshold manually to a higher level, it would take more time to reach this threshold and in my understanding the probability would increase to get a notification. Is there a way to modify this threshold?

This is the code that registers and listens to the notifications:

```
GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(gcThreshold, gcThreshold);
// Start a thread using WaitForFullGCProc.
thWaitForFullGC = new Thread(WaitForFullGCProc);
thWaitForFullGC.Name = "HealthTestGCNotificationListenerThread (Threshold=" + gcThreshold + ")";
thWaitForFullGC.IsBackground = true;
```

WaitForFullGCProc():

```
    private void WaitForFullGCProc()
{
    try
    {
        while (!gcAbort)
        {
            // Check for a notification of an approaching collection.
            GCNotificationStatus s;
            do
            {
                int timeOut = CheckForMissedGc() > 0 ? 5000 : (10 * 60 * 1000);
                s = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach(timeOut);
                if (this.GcState == GCState.InducedUnnotified)
                {
                    // Set the GcState back to okay to prevent the message from staying in the ApplicationMonitoring.
                    this.GcState = GCState.Okay;
                }
            } while (s == GCNotificationStatus.Timeout);

            if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
            {
                SetGcState(GCState.Approaching, "GC is approaching..");
                gcApproachNotificationCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            s = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete((int)PrewarnTime.TotalMilliseconds);
            long elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Timeout)
            {
                if (this.ForceGCWhenApproaching && !this.IsInGc && !this.IsPeriodicGcApproaching)
                {
                    this.IsInGc = true;
                    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, blocking: true);
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    this.IsInGc = false;
                }
            }
        }
        gcAbort = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you probably post the code where you register and listen for GC notifications?

Comment: `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(gcThreshold, gcThreshold);

// Start a thread using WaitForFullGCProc.
thWaitForFullGC = new Thread(WaitForFullGCProc);
thWaitForFullGC.Name = "HealthTestGCNotificationListenerThread (Threshold=" + gcThreshold + ")";
thWaitForFullGC.IsBackground = true;

Answer (score 4):

> Note: This is more of a comment but includes a large code sample.

Have you considered trying to get your GC notifications through another way? Jeffrey Richter ( CLR via C#) explains a good way to get notifications,it uses an object and checks its finalizer method in what generation it is.

This is the class: It uses internal objects which are either collected if the supplied generation matches ( See `new GenObject(0);` for example. ) or resurrected for the next higher generation.

And you just subscribe to it with `GCNotification.GCDone += GCDoneHandler;`

```
 public static class GCNotification
    {
        private static Action<Int32> s_gcDone = null; // The event's field
        public static event Action<Int32> GCDone
        {
            add
            {
                // If there were no registered delegates before, start reporting notifications now
                if (s_gcDone == null) { new GenObject(0); new GenObject(1); new GenObject(2); }
                s_gcDone += value;
            }
            remove { s_gcDone -= value; }
        }
        private sealed class GenObject
        {
            private Int32 m_generation;
            public GenObject(Int32 generation) { m_generation = generation; }
            ~GenObject()
            { // This is the Finalize method
                // If this object is in the generation we want (or higher),
                // notify the delegates that a GC just completed
                if (GC.GetGeneration(this) >= m_generation)
                {
                    Action<Int32> temp = Volatile.Read(ref s_gcDone);
                    if (temp != null) temp(m_generation);
                }
                // Keep reporting notifications if there is at least one delegate registered,
                // the AppDomain isn't unloading, and the process isn’t shutting down
                if ((s_gcDone != null)
                && !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload()
                && !Environment.HasShutdownStarted)
                {
                    // For Gen 0, create a new object; for Gen 2, resurrect the object
                    // & let the GC call Finalize again the next time Gen 2 is GC'd
                    if (m_generation == 0) new GenObject(0);
                    else GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
                }
                else { /* Let the objects go away */ }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but unfortunately it only notifies me after the GC has finished. It does not notify me about any upcoming garbage collections...